# Carousel like gallery in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, image-gallery

I'ld love to do something like this in jQueryMobile:

[Carousel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/carousel)

I don't need much more than a slider and the indicator which page is selected. It shall show some pictures.

So I testet a lot of Image Galleries. But most of them does

a) Have Thumbnails as initial interface or
b) doesn't work well with jQuery Mobile.

Does anybody know a simple way to get this started?

Comment: nivo slider is now responsive but not sure if it's 100% yet, I've personally used flex slider with jQuery Mobile and it works very well - http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/flexslider-demo/

Comment: this is interesting... http://swipejs.com/

Comment: I second @martincarlin87. I'm also using flexslider and it is more or less responive (you need to tweak the CSS a little), plus I also managed to replace the slider controls with "native" JQM elements, so my dots are icon-only buttons (without icon) for example.

Comment: [Photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) is probably what you're after, it is jquery mobile friendly (check the demos for examples).

Comment: @martincarlin87 flexSlider is a little buggy - but version 2 did the job for me!

Comment: @chrisben : Photoswipe is outdated. It won't work with new jQuery and jQuery Mobile versions.

Comment: @PascalTurbo : sure it does not seem to be actively maintained any more, though JQM doesn't work with latest jQuery yet either. I use photoswipe with latest JQM (1.1) it works ok.

Comment: You can also try Bootstrap-carosel.css , that works very well with this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Cubiq's [Swipeview](http://cubiq.org/swipeview) is really good, lightweight and responsive.

It has what you asked for and not much more. Of the sliders I've tested with jQM this is by far the most responsive.

In order for it to work with jQM you have three options:

1. Initialize before jQM
2. Wrap it in a pageshow
3. Place it in an iFrame

Comment: Tried the demo in the link on an Iphone 5s and this one looks cool! Works with swiping left and right.

Answer (score 2):

The default carousel built into Bootstrap is fairly good. Combined with some custom css it can work wonders. It has the option for thumbnails, and I am sure it will work with jQuery Mobile.
You can see it using the link below:

[Boostrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#carousel-example-generic)

Comment: Tried on an Iphone 5s and it looks cool but swiping does not work or is not supported. You have to press left/right arrows.

Answer (score 1):

ItemSlide.js is a great carousel for mobiles, it's simplistic, easy to use and small in size! A live demo along with documentation can be found here: http://itemslide.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

[Slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is a good little plugin and is fairly customisable.